# «И если друга есть плечо, беда нам не беда, и расстоянья нипочём...»

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, тире, слитно-раздельно

Нужно тире в песне «Поверь в себя»?
Ещё: как правильно писать — *ни по чём* или *нипочём*?

> И если друга есть плечо, беда нам (—) не беда, и расстоянья ни по чём (нипочём?), и не страшны года.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится: <...>
> **3)** если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание *не: **Офицер** этот **не чета** вам* (Фед.)...
> Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: *Но объяснение — не оправдание* (М. Г.); *Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?*..

• Автор, Н. Шемятенкова, делает такое подчеркивание и ставит тире.
• Кроме того, запятая ставится после первого союза "и" — для "отделения" придаточного.
• Наречие [нипочём](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71&dicts%5B%5D=42&dicts%5B%5D=30) выступает здесь в функции сказуемого (*кому?*). Пишется слитно.
*Нам расстоянья **нипочём.***

***И,** если друга есть плечо,

Беда нам **—** не беда,

И расстоянья **нипочём**,

И не страшны года.*

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92) (Розенталь)
[Поверь в себя](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/fel%27zman/noti/1%20(105).pdf) (Нотный архив России)

Comment: В конце 123-го написано, что, если сначала союз сочинительный, а потом — подчинительный и если они они начинают предложение, — запятая на стыке не ставится: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134.

Comment: Да, я думала над этой запятой. Во-первых, у Розенталя формулировка помягче: *3) перед придаточной частью запятая ставится в зависимости от значения присоединительного союза и наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении.* (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140) Во-вторых, тут можно считать союз "и" не присоединительным, а повторяющимся: ***И** Беда нам — не беда, **И** расстоянья нипочём, **И** не страшны года.* Предложения такого типа нет ни в ПАС, ни в справочнике Розенталя.

Comment: Но тут ведь главное предложение — это подчинительное *если друга есть плечо*, от которого все остальные зависят, т. е. исходят.